# Not Getting Response From Another Nodejs Server?

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, request, form-data

I am learning Nodejs. I am facing a small problem. I am uploading file to google cloud service. All types of files are uploading and I am getting signed URL of file. I am sending the signed URL from one nodejs server to another nodejs server. While uploading jpg or png file its success and getting response back to the another server.
But the issues is that, when I upload xlsx (excel file) I am not getting response to the another server. Its happing only while I upload the excel file only.

Any solution for that?

First Nodejs Server from where File is uploaded to GCS->

```
    if(is_valid_request){
        interface.gcpFileUpload(req, (data)=>{
            console.log("response = "+ JSON.stringify(data));
            res.json(data)
        })
    } else{
        res.json({success:0,err:"request is not valid"});
    }
```

Another server where I want to get response->

```
 getResponse(source, filename, destination, bucket_name, json_url, callback) {
    var formData = {
        file: fs.createReadStream(source),
        filename: filename,
        json_url: json_url,
        destination: destination,
        bucket_name: bname
    }
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': endpoint_of_another_server,
        'headers': {
            'api_key': key,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        formData: formData,
    }
    console.log("I AM RUNNING TILL HERE")
    request(options, function (error, response) {
        console.log("WE ARE GETTING SOME RESPONSE " + response);
        return callback(response.body);
    })
}
```

Comment: Any error or debug information? Can we see your implementation code for this please?

Comment: I updated the question please see.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to conclude on something without looking at the code snippets. But as per your problem statement, if it is only issue with *.xlsx (excel file) then it may have one of the below issue:

- You may need to allow *.xlsx file extension in your code
- If the file extension is already allowed, then there may be issue with the size of the file (assuming if it is having GBs of data)

Nevertheless, we can help you out more if you provide more details of code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your response, The file size is only 26kb, The file is uploaded successfully to the google cloud but the main issue is that only xlsx file's signed URL not received to another server. Even i am not getting any response in case of xlsx file.